# PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions block not called

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, xcode7, pffacebookutils

PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions block not called after update xcode7 and parse SDK to 1.8.5 and Facebook SDK 4.6 from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_friends", nil];
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
{
 if (!user) // The user cancelled the Facebook login
 {
     NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
 }
 else if (user.isNew) // New user (not stored on DB) - User signed up and logged in through Facebook
 {
     [self handleNewUser];
 }
 else if (user) // the user is exist at DB
 {
   // the user is exist at DB  
 }
 else if (error)
 {
    // showAlertOfSomethingWentWrong
 }
}];
```

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes i downgrade Facebook sdk to 4.5.1 and leave the xml like the iOS 9 tutorial.

Comment: Have been having the Same Experience with the New Facebook SDK... ANyone has been able to SOlve this?